# What is the purpose of X-Mx-ReqToken header?

Tags: http, header

What is the use of `X-Mx-ReqToken` HTTP header? Almost all tutorials on enabling CORS in nginx whitelist the `X-Mx-ReqToken` header. But I can't find any information on the purpose of the header.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`X-Mx-ReqToken` is a header used to supply a profiler key for [Mendix Runtime](https://apidocs.mendix.com/4/runtime/interfacecom_1_1mendix_1_1systemwideinterfaces_1_1core_1_1_i_profiler.html):

> **Member Data Documentation**
>
> final String com.mendix.systemwideinterfaces.core.IProfiler.PROFILER_KEY = "X-Mx-ReqToken" [static]

Basically, this is just a case of copying & pasting the same snippet over and over again until it made it to every nginx CORS tutorial out there. But unless you actually use said profiler, it's safe to omit.